# Built-in preprocessor token to detect iPhone app target

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to set up correctly the FIRM ID for my app(according to target).For example I wrote in my Distribution.h the following lines:

```
#define X_FIRM_ID @"X"
#define XX_FIRM_ID @"XX"

#define FIRM_ID XX_FIRM_ID
```

For each build that I made I must manually change the FIRM_ID.I want to this automatically, just like I do for Default.png and other images used in my apps.
I have 2 targets: one for X and another one for XX.In each target I filled the Preprocessor macros with X and XX accordingly.

Now I want to define in Distribution.h the FIRM_ID accordingly with the preprocessor macro and I don't know how to do this.

```
#define FIRM_ID if defined(XX) XX
```

The above one do not work.

Please help me with this, if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here are two:

- In your target info, under build, set `Preprocessor macros`
- Import different `Prefix headers` for the two targets

Comment: #if defined(XX)
        #import DistributionXX.h
    #endif